# Differences in date string parsing between Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, date, time

With Ruby 1.8.7:

```
>> require 'time'
>> Time.parse '01/28/2012'
=> Sat Jan 28 00:00:00 +0200 2012
>> Time.parse '28/01/2012'
=> ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

With Ruby 1.9.3:

```
>> require 'time'
>> Time.parse '28/01/2012'
=> 2012-01-28 00:00:00 +0200
>> Time.parse '01/28/2012'
=> ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

It looks like in Ruby 1.8.7 it was accepting US format (month/day/year), while in Ruby 1.9.3 it accepts only non US format (day/month/year).

Is there a way to change this behavior to be like Ruby 1.8.7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it be an option for you to use `Time.strptime("01/28/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")` in place of `Time.parse`? That way you have better control over how Ruby is going to parse the date.

If not there are gems: (e.g. [ruby-american_date](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date)) to make the Ruby 1.9 Time.parse behave like Ruby 1.8.7, but only use it if it's absolutely necessary.

```
1.9.3-p0 :002 > Time.parse '01/28/2012'
ArgumentError: argument out of range

1.9.3-p0 :003 > require 'american_date'
1.9.3-p0 :004 > Time.parse '01/28/2012'
 => 2012-01-28 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Ruby can only guesstimate date formats so well, and American formatting is infuriating because of ambiguity. `01/02/03` is...what exactly? `YY/MM/DD`? `DD/MM/YY`? `MM/DD/YY`?

Comment: Because the code in question is using Rails' `String#to_time`, which uses `Time.parse` I was looking for a solution to change the way `Time.parse` works. If it wasn't an existing code, I would definitely use `Time.strptime` -- far more robust. Thank you for pointing out the ruby-american_date gem!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9.3 appears to have changed the default date parsing format...

In Ruby 1.8.7

```
"11/14/2012".to_time
==> Wed Nov 14 00:00:00 UTC 2012
```

In Ruby 1.9.3

```
"11/14/2012".to_time
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

The to_time conversion now accepts %d,%m,%Y as the string format...

In Ruby 1.9.3

```
"14/11/2012".to_time
2012-11-14 00:00:00 UTC
```

Notice the different format of the output.  Time.now.to_s also returns a different format in 1.9.3.  Watch out!

I saw another post that said that to_time was purposely deprecated in Ruby 1.9.3, but it appears that only the parsing format was changed.

Furthermore...

In 1.8.7

```
Time.parse("11/14/2012", "%m,%d,%Y")
==> Wed Nov 14 06:00:00 UTC 2012
```

In 1.9.3

```
Time.parse("11/13/2012", "%m,%d,%Y")
==> ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

Time.strptime does not exist in 1.8.7, only in 1.9.3, so I do not see a way to make my code backward compatible to 1.8.7 after making the necessary changes for 1.9.3.